# Why do highly-optimizing compilers not utilize the ANDNOT instruction?

Tags: compiler-optimization

First off: I mainly develop games in C# using Unity3D. That means I don't have access to .Net Core intrinsics but rather SIMD intrinsics provided by the Burst Compiler made by Unity Technologies - otherwise I wouldn't ask.

I find myself to be using the andnot semantics a ton when doing bit-manipulation where I need >>both<< the original and the inverted value of a bitmask within a small function, which is probably the most optimal use case for it.

I tried to force the fully-optimizing compiler to generate it by defining it as a function both as

```
static inline int andnot(int a, int b)
{
    return ~a & b;
}
```

and even as

```
static inline int andnot(int a, int b)
{
    __m128i whyDoIHaveToDoThis = _mm_insert_epi32(_mm_setzero_si128(), a, 0);
    __m128i compilersAreWaySmarterThanThis = _mm_insert_epi32(_mm_setzero_si128(), b, 0);

    return _mm_extract_epi32(_mm_andnot_si128(whyDoIHaveToDoThis, compilersAreWaySmarterThanThis, 0);
}
```

and both produce assemblies like

```
not   a, a
and   b, b, a
```

(yes, even the second function outputs this)

? 
According to Agner Fog's instruction tables, the latency of "andn" is one clock cycle with one micro-op and a reciprocal throughput of 0.5 and this has been true for at least a decade (seems to be trivial to implement in the hardware aswell).
So let me reiterate; why do compilers not use the instruction even if I try my hardest to tell them to?

Comment: What architecture are you targeting? ANDN is a BMI1 instruction.

Comment: When generating this assembly, I was targeting Avx2, which includes Sse4.1, which includes BMI